# How to add horizontal scroller to specific number of columns in HTML table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, horizontal-scrolling

I have a HTML table with 20 columns. In that table, I want first 10 columns fixed and rest all columns horizontal scrollable as shown in following image.

[image]

I tried a lot but I am not getting how to do it.
can anyone help me out to resolve this issue.
If you want any further information I can provide you the same.

Waiting for your replies.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/trFPD/397/ check this fiddle

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian:This is similar to my requirement. But I want simple HTML CSS code which can add horizontal scroll bar to the later columns in table.

Answer (score 1):

I did it once (with one fixed row and one fixed column, the rest was scrollable) and I've had quite a hard time.

The only thing I came up with was to have more than one table (2 in your case) contained in a parent container (div or outer table).

The thing is quite easy if you can fix the heights of the rows (make them equal in both tables), a bit harder if you need the content of the cells to decide the height.

In that case you need a javascript function to be called after the creation of the table which sets the heights of each row to be the maximum value of the heights in the two tables (so for each row "i" you need to get

`h=max(table1.row[i].cell[1].height,table2.row[i].cell[1].height)` and set `table1.row[i].cell[1].height = h and table2.row[i].cell[1].height = h`.

This is obviously only the rough idea, not even pseudo code.

## [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgNMT/1/)

Comment: I changed the fiddle a little bit to make it more like what I think @AnandJaju was looking for

Comment: sorry, I probably did something wrong with the fiddle and it restored a version before my editing. Now I forked it: [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgNMT/1/)